# cakephp server side validation issue

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

On my registration page, I have radio button to select user type, **competitor** or **noncompetitor** and both users have different database table to register into.

Now when I go for validation, my url is like, `noncompetitors/register` and here is a whole form to enter registration information, now when user selects noncompetitor registration, it displays server side validations which cakephp provides, but when user tries to register with competitor, it doesn't go for server side validadtions, what can i do to apply both diff models validations to a single form, depending on registration selection?

Earliest reply would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: what version of cakephp do you use? and are competitor and noncompetitor different models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to be more specific.  If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to validate one or more fields in the form differently depending on whether someone selects *competitor* or *noncompetitor*.  Is that right?  Otherwise, please clarify your question.

If so, it seems like you could directly test the input.  Something like this:

```
if($this->data['RegisterType'] == 'competitor' ) {
   [check to see if the field(s) your testing meet criteria X]
} else {
   [check to see if the field(s) your testing meet criteria X]
}
```

Again, I'm guessing at the issue, but hopefully I understood the question.

Comment: yes you've understood it correctly, in single form of registration, we have two types of users, **competitors** or **non-competitors** registration, which needs to be validate